# cordova app displays a black screen before splash screen displays

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I'm developing a web app with Intel XDK which builds my app with Cordova online.
I add a splash screen with the splash screen plugin. And the splash screen appears when I launch my app. But before the splash screen shows, a black screen shows for a little while first. How could I make it shows the splash screen immediately without a black screen first.

I googled for days..And I find many others had this problem. But it seems the solutions can not help me..

I have tried set AutoHideSplashScreen to false and SplashScreenDelay = 10000(or higher), and hide the splash screen when all things are ready(app.Ready, deviceready..)

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: More information please. On which device does the error occur?

Comment: this is not an error, this happens on all devices while it loads cordova

Answer (score 4):

1) if you use some **splashscreen.png** you can create android style file under **{Project}\res\values** (for example splashscreen-style.xml) and put splashscreen.png into **{Project}\res\drawable** folder (or **drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi**, ...), it will be mapped in automatically **@drawable/splashscreen**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="YourThemeName" parent="android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

2) Apply your the by **config.xml**:

```
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge"
             target="/manifest/application/activity">
        <activity android:theme="@style/YourThemeName" />
    </edit-config>
```

It must work, at least for **cordova 6.5.0**:) and **some eralier version**.

Also you can see https://simonerescio.it/en/2014/05/phonegap-android-splashscreen-application

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this after lot of researchs.

Firstly go to **intelxdk.config.additions.xml** file

add this line on top

`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000" />`**//change value depending on ur needs in milliseconds**

**Also modify the FadeSplashScreenDuration (iOS)**

```
      `<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="8000"/>`
```

Here is the full code

```
<!-- 'value' = number of milliseconds to display the splash screen in a Cordova build. -->
<!-- This preference only affects Cordova builds for Crosswalk and Android. -->
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000" /> 

<platform name="ios">
    <!-- below requires the splash screen plugin -->
    <!-- docs: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen -->
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="8000"/>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>

    <!-- below requires the status bar plugin -->
    <!-- docs: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar -->
    <!-- see http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid -->
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
</platform>

<platform name="android">
    <!-- below requires the splash screen plugin -->
    <!-- docs: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen -->
      <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
</platform>

<!-- use this feature to add command-lines to be used by Crosswalk builds on device -->
<!-- see http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ for complete list -->
<intelxdk:crosswalk xwalk-command-line="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
<!-- ignore gpu blacklist for larger collection of gpu accelerated devices -->
<intelxdk:crosswalk xwalk-command-line="--ignore-gpu-blacklist" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the documentation is a little disjointed.

Config.XML ensure you have the following lines.
Android:  Adjust time out period to what suits.(10000 for me as I pre-load some pages in DOM).

```
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

Ios:

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

in Index.Js

```
function () {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
function onDeviceReady() {
setTimeout(function () {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 50);
}
```

This kept the splash screen open until the platform was ready for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to confi.xml and try this code. It works for me.

```
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="5000"/> 
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" /> 



<!-- Ionic supports Android Jellybean and up --> 
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />

<!-- Don't store local data in an iCloud backup. Turn this to "cloud" to enable storage 
     to be sent to iCloud. Note: enabling this could result in Apple rejecting your app.
-->
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />

<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen"/>
  <param name="onload" value="true"/>
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to platform/android/AndroidMainfest.xml .
And search android:theme="android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar".

```
Android will load a blank layout before it loads based on the theme you have set for it. The solution is to the theme of the splash activity to a transparent one.
```

And change it to like this android:theme="android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoActionBar".